# What is the meaning of a bearing exactly?

Tags: c++

I have encountered this bearing concept as the following.

Background:
        Given the profile "testbot"
        And a grid size of 10 meters

```
Scenario: Testbot - Intial bearing in simple case
    Given the node map
        """
        a b c d
        """

    And the ways
        | nodes |
        | ad    |

    When I route I should get
        | from | to | bearings  | route | bearing    |
        | b    | c  | 90 90     | ad,ad | 0->90,90->0|
        | b    | c  | 180 90    |       |            |
        | b    | c  | 80 100    | ad,ad | 0->90,90->0|
        | b    | c  | 79 100    |       |            |
        | b    | c  | 79,11 100 | ad,ad | 0->90,90->0|

Scenario: Testbot - Intial bearing in simple case
    Given the node map
        """
        a
        0 c
        b
        """

    And the ways
        | nodes |
        | ac    |
        | bc    |

    When I route I should get
        | from | to | bearings | route | bearing       |
        | 0    | c  | 0 0      |       |               |
        | 0    | c  | 45 45    | bc,bc | 0->45,45->0   |
        | 0    | c  | 85 85    |       |               |
        | 0    | c  | 95 95    |       |               |
        | 0    | c  | 135 135  | ac,ac | 0->135,135->0 |
        | 0    | c  | 180 180  |       |               |

Scenario: Testbot - Initial bearing on split way
    Given the node map
       """
       g d 2       1         c f
       h a         0         b e
       """

    And the ways
        | nodes | oneway |
        | ab    | yes    |
        | bc    | yes    |
        | cd    | yes    |
        | da    | yes    |
        | be    | yes    |
        | fc    | yes    |
        | dg    | yes    |
        | ha    | yes    |

    When I route I should get
        | from | to | bearings | route       | bearing                    |
        | 0    | b  | 10 10    | bc,bc       | 0->0,0->0                  |
        | 0    | b  | 90 90    | ab,ab       | 0->90,90->0                |
        | 0    | b  | 170 170  | da,da       | 0->180,180->0              |
        | 0    | b  | 189 189  | da,da       | 0->180,180->0              |
        | 0    | 1  | 90 270   | ab,cd,cd    | 0->90,90->0,270->0         |
        | 1    | 2  | 10 10    | bc,bc       | 0->0,0->0                  |
        | 1    | 2  | 90 90    | ab,cd,ab,ab | 0->90,90->0,270->180,90->0 |
        | 1    | 0  | 189 189  | da,da       | 0->180,180->0              |
        | 1    | 2  | 270 270  | cd,cd       | 0->270,270->0              |
        | 1    | 2  | 349 349  |             |                            |
```

It really confused me. Moreover, the bearing.hpp file is as the following.

```
namespace engine               
{

struct Bearing
{
    short bearing;
    short range;

    bool IsValid() const { return bearing >= 0 && bearing <= 360 && range >= 0 && range <= 180; }
};

inline bool operator==(const Bearing lhs, const Bearing rhs)
{
    return lhs.bearing == rhs.bearing && lhs.range == rhs.range;
}
inline bool operator!=(const Bearing lhs, const Bearing rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }
}
```

I understand that the bearing here is related to the direction / angle of the vehicle movement, right? Based on wiki, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Compass_Bearings, I got a rough sense of what it is. After viewing this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T40AMljjgrU I understand what is the bearing between two given locations in a map. Still, I need more clarifications with respect to the above scenario. More specially, what is exactly 0->0, 0->90 when talking about bearings?

Comment: "A bearing is a direction. Bearings are measured clockwise from north, so north is zero degrees, east is 90 degrees, south is 180 degrees, and west is 270 degrees. In trigonometry, an angle is a measure of rotation from one ray to another ray with the same endpoint."

Comment: The thing is, what is exactly 0->90? Given two points A and B, during the straight-line-movement from A to B, the bearing between A and B does not change.